# Is there any reaction where electrons or protons get directly converted to energy, and are destroyed as a consequence?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, mass-energy, antimatter, protons

This question is not about fission or fusion reactions, or changes in mass/energy as the speed of a particle changes. The number of protons (including protons within neutrons) and electrons pre- and post-fission and fusion are the same, and the number of protons and electrons are independent of velocity. Some think Einstein's equation means that mass actually can be converted to energy. But his equation is about equivalence, not conversion. So the question is: is there any reaction where electrons or protons (or the elementary particles (quarks) that constitute a proton) literally get converted to energy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation

Comment: Search terms: lepton number conservation, baryon number conservation.

Answer (score 3):

yes. electrons are converted into pure energy when one collides with its  *antiparticle*.

Comment: Actually as proton is not an elementary particle, the annihilation is not 'perfect'. Other particles are created.

Comment: When an electron collides with a positron (anti-electron), aren't two photons created? Do you call photons "pure energy"? If so, why?

Comment: photons qualify as pure energy.

Comment: @fanyul, thank you , will edit.

Comment: @md2perpe Photons might be considered as pure energy, because they are massless, and they can transfer **all** their energy to other particles. (For example to an electron through the photoelectric effect.)

Comment: Poorly worded question on my part. I should have excluded reactions with antiparticles, an obvious example, even if not associated with reactions such as fission, fusion, or candle-burning. Thanks Niels. But fission, fusion, and candle-burning do not convert resting mass into energy, as protons and electrons are preserved. So, besides interactions with anti-particles, are there any other reactions where protons or electrons are effectively destroyed in order to be "converted" to energy?

Comment: see anna v's answer below. this is a complex topic.

Comment: @fanyul. Energy is just a scalar. Energy doesn't have spin. Photons have spin.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes. I forgot to add that in my opinion it is not  a good analogy to consider photons as 'pure energy'.

Comment: @fanyul. I totally agree. Recently I had a discussion with a guy who thought that $E=mc^2$ was about conversion between mass and energy, that you either have mass or energy. I wrote that the equation rather says that mass and energy are the same thing. He thought that I was trolling.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, after your comments to the correct answer of Niels to  your question, the question  is  really:

" can the rest mass of an [**elementary** particle be totally converted to energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)  .

The rest mass of protons and neutrons can be partially converted to energy, by the [definition of "mass"](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html),  the quarks feeding a quark gluon plasma. See [what a proton is made of](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/) in terms of elementary particle four vectors added up to give its mass.

In the standard model of physics masses to elementary particles are provided by the [symmetry breaking Higgs mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism) . When the energies are very high every elementary particle has zero mass , and in the [cosmological models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) acquires a mass with symmetry breaking.

Of course this  energy is not something that can be achieved  in the present day laboratory, so the answer to the question is that *elementary particles keep their rest mass*.